# How can i solve : Configuration with name 'compileClasspath' not found

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, gradle-kotlin-dsl

**As** i found when we want to use specific version of **dependency** in **Gradle** we have **3** ways :

The **first** **one** is **strict** **version** like this :

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp") {
   version { 
       strictly("3.12.12")
   }
}
```

**This way does not work on okhttp for me and i dont know why!**

**The** **second** way using **force** like this :

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12") {
   isForce = true
}
```

**This way work for me but it is deprecated**

**The** **third** way using **resolutionStrategy** like this :

```
configurations {
    "compileClasspath" {
        resolutionStrategy.force("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12")
    }
}
```

**In this way i faced with this error :**

```
Configuration with name 'compileClasspath' not found.
```

**So my question is how can i use the third way? if it be located at the bottom of the dependency block its enough?**

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `configurations.all` like :

```
configurations.all { 
    resolutionStrategy.force("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i used this before and it does not work for me as first way.